# String interpolation using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out the React way of doing the following:

I have an url that I get from my server with placeholders for url parameters:

`http://localhost/{someSlug}/?FirstParameter={FirstParameter}&SecondParamter={SecondParameter}`

under the url I have an input field for each parameter, or slug, which should update the url using state.

I solved it quickly by using jquery and regex. I wrapped the Parameter value in a `<span data="{FirstParameter}">{FirstParameter}</span>`.

`http://localhost/<span data="{someSlug}">{someSlug}</span>/?FirstParameter=<span data="{FirstParameter}>{FirstParameter}</span>&SecondParamte‌​r=<span data="{SecondParameter}">{SecondParameter}<span>`

Which allowed me to find and replace the value when ever the input changes.

```
const $el = $(`span[data="{${prop}}"]`);
$el.text(e.target.value);
if ($el.text().trim() === '') {
  $el.text(`{${prop}}`)
}
```

But I am wondering how I would solve this without jQuery.

Comment: *"I solved it quickly by using jquery and regex."* That doesn't sound like you are doing *string interpolation*. Can you provide a more complete example? React doesn't provide any helper methods for string interpolation. You just do whatever you usually do in JavaScript.

Comment: I used regex to add a span around the {ParamterValue} so the url would look like `http://localhost/<span data="{someSlug}">{someSlug}</span>/?FirstParameter=<span data="{FirstParameter}>{FirstParameter}</span>&SecondParamter=<span data="{SecondParameter}">{SecondParameter}<span>`

Comment: What are the `span`s for?

Comment: @JacobSDK please add to your question that  
"The url comes from the server as a string with the placeholders" or clarify what you mean.